# How these UITableView section index lays over the cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get UITbaleView section index same as in screenshot, the section index is without any background and is laying over the UITableView cells, or in other words there is no UITableView margin on right:

[image]

But my UITableView have some about 15-20px contentView margin on right.

I tried `self.tableView.layoutMargins = .zero`, `self.tableView.separatorInset = .zero` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was actually easy done with following 2 lines:

```
tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = .clear
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .clear
```